# How can you fill a NumPy array with another array (possibly with different shape)

Tags: python, numpy

Not sure how to ask my question, maybe the title doesn't reflect my question correctly, and if that is the case feel free to correct me.

I have two arrays

```
a = np.zeros((2, 2))
b = np.ones((3, 3))
```

I want a func that would yield the following result:

```
c = func(a, b)
print(c)

# array([[1., 1.],
#       [1., 1.]])
```

But if we switch position of `a` and `b` when we pass them to the function, we will get the following result:

```
c = func(b, a) # Note the change
print(c)

# array([[0., 0., 1.],
#       [0., 0., 1.],
#       [1., 1., 1.]])
```

Edit: for clarification, here is another example to answer @mercury's question.

```
a = np.zeros((2, 3))
b = np.ones((3, 2))

c = func(a, b)
print(c)

# array([[1., 1., 0.],
#       [1., 1., 0.]])
```

Comment: Some clarifications: what if a has shape (2,3) and b has shape (3,2) (Each array is bigger in a different dimension). Or are the arrays always nxn square arrays?

Comment: @Mercury I added another example to the post that should answer your question

Comment: So you want to keep the shape of the first array and replace all elements of it with the elements of the second array, if the second array has these elements?

Comment: @NiklasMertsch Yes, that's pretty much it.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found an answer, not sure about it tho.

```
def func(a, b):
    x1, x2 = np.min((a.shape, b.shape), 0)
    c = a.copy()
    c[:x1, :x2] = b[:x1, :x2]
    return c
```

I'll be happy if someone who understands the question could reply if this actually solves it, and if so, how should this operation be called?

Comment: Looks good to me. If I understood your question correctly, something like this would be my answer.

Comment: @NiklasMertsch thank you for your answer, how would you call this operation btw? I thought something along the lines of `fill_array` but I'm not sure if it fully reflects the idea of the function.

Comment: This is your brainchild, name it however you want. If you solve some specific problem with it, maybe that problems gives you some inspiration. `fill_existing(base, fill)`?

Comment: @NiklasMertsch Thank you for your answer. If you are familiar with neural networks, I am using this function to connect the weights of two layers in a neural network while compensating for missing connections (for genetic a genetic algorithm).